# Substantiv für etwas Grundlegendes?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

Für mein Inhaltsverzeichnis suche ich **ein Wort**, das eine Seite aus meiner Arbeit zusammenfasst, in der ich nur ein paar Stichpunkte zu einer Software gemacht habe.

Diese Stichpunkte beinhalten einfach grundlegende Informationen (Wer, Wann, Wo, Was) über die Software, aber wie sagt man das in einem Wort?

> Seite 1 Grundlegendes

Klingt blöd.
*Funktion* gefällt mir auch nicht, da ich auch mehr als die Funktion erkläre.

Habt ihr vielleicht (**mehrere**) Vorschläge?

Comment: Gibt es einen besonderen Grund, warum es nur ein Wort sein darf?

Comment: Sag mal ein paar andere Stichtpunkte aus dem Inhaltsverzeichnis, das würde mir helfen, was passendes zu finden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Englisch wird dieser Abschnitt jeweils mit "Abstract" überschrieben. Im Deutschen würde ich "Überblick", "Übersicht", "Einleitung" oder "Zusammenfassung" brauchen. Vielleicht auch "Kurzbeschreibung", je nach Inhalt.

Comment: "Abstract" ist (gemäß Duden) auch im Deutschen korrekt; darüber, wie schön das jedoch ist, lässt sich streiten.

Answer (score 3):

Wie wäre es mit

- Abstract
- Grundlagen
- Vorbemerkungen
- Einführung
- ...